# Where to Configure Properties for the New Custom Font Type?

Tags: 2013, rtf

We have added our custom Font type to CMS using `Open Font List` option available under Administration Tab, as mentioned in the [SDL Live Doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-5951DD92-72A0-4DCD-9758-AE2EABB3B478#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dfont%2520configuratuon&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1455030192142&currentQuery=font%2520configuratuon&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B92ABEEE-5932-4431-833D-F9291A1F3144&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-B92ABEEE-5932-4431-833D-F9291A1F3144.xml&docid=GUID-B92ABEEE-5932-4431-833D-F9291A1F3144&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false). But we are not able to find the place where we need to add the font type properties.
 1) Do we need to Install the Font first in server?
 2) For existing font type i.e Arial, Arial Black e.t.c., We couldn't find any Css file where we can extend and add our new font type details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no configuration available for the fonts. The only thing you can set is the name of the font to be available in the the list of fonts, that the Editors can select for the rich text format fields.

The selected font is translated to the following in the rich text field,

```
<span style="font-family: FONT-NAME;">componente</span>
```

So to install a type of font not available by default in all browsers, I think that it is necessary to add a "**font-face**" in your application css files.
For example try loading your font files with:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myOwnFont;
    src: url('myOwnFont.woff');
}
```

If you want to see the results of this font in the Field Editor of the Content Manager Explorer, then you have to add this font face to a css file loaded by the content manager, for example the "**FormatAreaStyles.css**" file in the following path:

```
<TRIDION>\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration\
```

Comment: what will be the `src: Url`, is it where the font is installed?

Comment: If you put the woff file in the same path as the FormatAreaStyles, and put the url with quotes like url('myOwnFornt.woff') it works

Comment: I installed them in Windows fonts Folder where other fonts are alrady installed in server and giving url as <br> src: `url("../fonts/myOwnFornt.woff");` . But not fonts not working in RTF. any suggestions

Comment: Forget the Windows Fonts. Put your .woff file in the same path as the FormatAreaStyles.css, and configure the font-face as I told you in that file. Is all you need to see your fonts displayes in the RichTextFormat field.

Comment: thank you @RaulEscudero ... now i am getting my fonts working, except the Italic one. Tying to make it work.

Comment: now italic fonts also working. :)